# How to optimally define permissions based on content with TypeORM

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using MS SQL Server + TypeORM with Nestjs to build an API.

There are different tables created on the already created in the database, like:
`User`, `Client`, `Country`, `Building`, `Asset`.

I want that the content that users are able to see is filtered based on some criteria (like Client and Building), for that reason I've defined some intermediate tables to assign permissions to users:
`ClientUserPermission`, `BuildingUserPermission`.

All these tables are mapped with TypeORM with their own Entity Repository.
So to get the data from each entity, and what I do to filter the content per user is:

1. First call to retrieve the ids of an entity from its corresponding permissions table, using the id of the user.
2. Second call to the targeted entity, filtering the data by the previous ids using the IN operator.

For example, to load all assets that a user can see:
`Assets` have `buildingIds` assigned, and `BuildingUserPermissions` have possible combinations of `userId` and `buildingId`, so I do the following:

```js
public async findAllAssetsByUser({...}: QueryParamsDto, userId?: string): Promise<Asset[]> {
    ...
    // Call permissions service, and get allowed buildings per user.
    const allowedBuildings= await this.permissionsService.findAllowedBuildingsByUser(userId);

    // Retrieve assets filtered by users allowed buildings.
    const data = await this.assetsRepo.find({
      ...,
      where: {
        ...,
        buildingId: In([allowedBuildings]),
        ...,
      },
      ...,
    });

    return data;
}
```

I think that there's probably a better way of doing this so I don't have to do one ore more extra calls to get first the permissions.

I've thought that maybe it would be better to query the data using a query builder to automatically do joins with the corresponding permissions table.

If there are better ways please tell me.